# Paginate with Descending Timestamp in Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im having trouble paginating data by its descending timestamp in Firestore (fetch newest first). When I order by

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("items")
        .order(by: "date", descending: true)
        .limit(to: 3)
```

it works, but if I try to refresh it just loads the same data. To paginate I tried

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("items")
        .order(by: "random", descending: true)
        .start(after: [lastFetchedItem?.random ?? ""])
        .limit(to: 1)
```

which fetches data based on a random number generator and it paginates perfectly each time so I know its possible. Now if I try

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("items")
        .order(by: "date", descending: true)
        .start(after: [lastFetchedItem?.date ?? ""])
        .limit(to: 1)
```

I load the first item but can't paginate to the next. I record the timestamp with Timestamp(date: Date()) and in my dictionary my date is written as

```
var date: Date?
    
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.date = dictionary["date"] as? Date
    }
```

Comment: What's your mechanism to load additional pages (when the user scrolls to the bottom, a button tap, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up formatting the date field as a unix timestamp which gave me an Int such as I did with .random. Then I ordered by the date. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

To paginate, pass in the entire snapshot of the last item on the previous page. Passing in single values as you do is not going to work.

So if your `lastFetchedItem` is the document snapshot:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("items")
        .order(by: "date", descending: true)
        .start(after: lastFetchedItem)
        .limit(to: 1)
```