# Firestore: Can't Paginate Queries with descending order

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a paginated query where the results are returned in descending order on the `timestamp` field of my Firestore collection. I am passing the last document snapshot in the `startAfter` argument. If I don't make the order descending, it works perfectly.

The following works perfectly. Note the variable `lastDocSnapshot` is my own variable where I just pass the last snapshot of the 12 previous docs I received:

This works:

```
let query = db.collection('actions')

query
.orderBy('timestamp')
.startAfter(lastDocnapshot)
.limit(12)
.get()
.then(snapshot => {
  // The snapshot contains 12 documents here as I expected.
})
```

Here is a screenshot of the console returning the 12 docs as expected:
[image]
And I can of course get data from those document snapshots, here is one doc expanded (all test data which I am going to delete)
[image]

However, when I try to make the `orderBy` descending, it returns no data. There is no error either. The snapshot itself is empty, the snapshot.empty check is true.

This does not work:

```
let query = db.collection('actions')

query
.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
.startAfter(lastDocnapshot)
.limit(12)
.get()
.then(snapshot => {
  // The snapshot contains no documents.
})
```

The snapshot is empty in the console:

[image]

The only thing I'm changing is the descending order in the `orderBy`. I've also tried other fields that are not timestamps, like strings and ints. Works perfectly when the default ascending order is applied, but it never works if there is a **descending** `orderBy` and a `startAfter`.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63679263/paginate-with-descending-timestamp-in-firestore) but I don't want to go and change all my thousands of existing documents to unix timestamps. Also, I've tried descending order on other fields that are just integers and the same issue occurs anyway.

Any ideas on why this could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of a document from the Firebase console? It'd probably also help to see the document that you expected to get back from the second query vs the one that you actually got back.

Comment: Thanks Puf, I added the screenshots as requested. I also edited the text slightly, the snapshot itself when adding the descending order comes back as empty. Also, you'll see there is a field actionNumber, I tried doing descending with that string, it also only works on ascending.

Comment: Interesting. It's almost like there is no index on descending `date`, but if that were the case it should throw an error (with a link to create the index).

Comment: Yes, I also thought it could be an indexing issue, but I do have an index created for timestamp descending and another field I am always querying by, which is a bool called 'open'. I tried adding that field to the query as well to try and match the condition of that index, but it still just returns an empty snapshot and no error. Anyway, this is not a super crucial part of my app, at least :)

Comment: Why don't you make a quick script that updates your documents to UNIX timestamps, if that can solve your issue, why not?

Comment: I'll give that a try @Barraguesh

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to have data in descending order...Instead of using startAfter you can use endBefore(null) query at first like this.

```
query
.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
.endBefore(null) //Or emit this field
.limit(12)
.get()
 .then(snapshot => {
  // The snapshot contains no documents.
 })
```

Then for next set of data use another query with startAfter

```
query
.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
.startAfter(lastDocumentSnap),
.limit(12)
.get()
 .then(snapshot => {
  // The snapshot contains no documents.
 })
```